# Given admission based on current GPA for graduate school, but GPA drops during final term

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

How do graduate student admissions work if a student meets requirements at time of application, gets accepted, and drops below minimum requirements during their final term before graduation?

For example, if a school requires a minimum GPA to get admission, and a student applied in his final year with a sufficiently high GPA and got admission in March, and by the end of the year (before finishing school to submit the complete transcript and GPA), the university finds a GPA that is not sufficiently high, how would the university handle this?

Comment: I made a few edits that I hope clarify your question. Feel free to revert the edits if they do not convey your question accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be very rare to not honor the earlier decision as long as you still graduate. Other things, such as misbehavior could change an acceptance, but a drop in the final term GPA wouldn't normally do it.

People giving early acceptance realize that things don't always go smoothly. And changing the decision at a late point is disruptive to that program as well.

I suggest you relax. It isn't impossible, but it would be exceptional, not normal if the decision were to change.

Note that I'm assuming a relatively normal variation in GPA. A drop to all failures in the final term would be different, but it would probably also deny you graduation.

And also note that a drop in the final term is fairly normal and common since people start to think about other things at that point.